# Failed to install Windows on Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, windows, 20.10

In many days I had tried to install Windows on an Ubuntu computer, but when I partition the disk, I left too much space for Windows. And I don’t know why but Windows 10 setup doesn’t recognize the partition. When I tried to boot back into Ubuntu, it couldn’t boot back into Ubuntu. So I tried many ways to rescue, from reinstalling Ubuntu to installing from Windows Vista, but all failed. So at the end I chose the latter, which is to install Ubuntu back on the computer. But now it couldn’t boot up, here’s what happened when I turned on the computer (video link) :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pjlqcL-TrjhZFYI9CqQoglKRqfytmA6o/view?usp=sharing

And here’s what’s inside the Ubuntu installation medium (labeled as UBUNTU 20_1, video link):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RsLthKxZJ-G2Z0COMOn9YaIWZ9irY8Xw/view?usp=sharing

My computer is an Dell Vostro 14-5459. Thank you.

Comment: It works best if Windows is installed BEFORE Ubuntu.

Comment: I did do that, but then I installed Ubuntu and then when I see the inconvenience of installing software I just tried to installed Windows 10 again

Comment: How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. And Windows in UEFI boot mode has to have gpt partitioning and wants multiple partitions. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations  Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred My computer boot mode is UEFI, but I could barely enter the boot menu! And I was too late to type the command `sudo parted -l` because now my computer is stuck at the screen!

Comment: You need to run that from working system. Boot your Ubuntu live installer and run command from there.